# Does Lightswitch 2-tier Desktop App require SQL server on client?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I've created a simple Lightswitch 2-tier desktop app that connects to a remote sql db. I've published it, and the install.htm file specifies that SQL Server 2005/Express (or later) must first be installed on the client machine. Can that be right? Does Lightswitch always use SQL Server/Express for some native part of the program? Or did I somehow unwittingly/inadvertantly create local data objects?
I know for sure that LS requires Silverlight on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the auto-generated install.htm is boilerplate. In this case, it wrongly states that some flavor of sql server is required on the client. The answer to my question turns out to be "no." In this case, the same applies for the install.htm remarks regarding sql commands at the command prompt as well.